# Edit Dictionary in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary

I have a view-model "MyClass" that contains a dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, bool> columns {get; set;}
```

and it has keys and values

```
 columns.Add("Name", true);
 columns.Add("Type", true);
```

now, I want to let the user edit MyClass and its dictionary.

For **every key** I want to show its key and to enable to check\unchek its value (true\false), such that the input's name will be the right name for editing. since the dictionary has many keys, I need to to it with "foreach" or "for".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: @tamarg So then you must know how to generate html with inputs,check boxes, how to pass model in controller and how to send json to controller actions.

Comment: I did it for lists but I can't do it for dictionaries in the class. Have you read my question at all?

Comment: @tamarg you can pass list<string> (only checked items) to controller action and there update your dictionary if i understand you right

Comment: So I can't do it with dictionary in the view? only indirectly with lists?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this in your View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MyClassViewModel</legend>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Columns){
            @Html.Label(item.Key)
            @Html.CheckBox(item.Key, item.Value)
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and your view must be bind to model in that case

```
@model MvcDemoApp.Models.MyClassViewModel
```

or as an alternative

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Columns)
    {
        @item.Key 
        <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Key" checked="@item.Value" />
        <input type="hidden" value="@item.Value" />
        <br />
    }
```

or try using CheckBoxList custom helper by community

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/05/05/asp-net-mvc-implementing-checkboxlist.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension

Comment: It doesn't help, because the html is
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Id" id="Id" checked="checked">
and the name doesn't fit to the dictionary's name.

Comment: At my end, it's like
<input checked="checked" id="Type" name="Type" type="checkbox" value="true" />

Where as "Type" is key in dictionary with value true...

Can you please elaborate your question a little more and share what exactly model you are binding in view and passing from controller?

Comment: FYI I am using MVC 3 and Razar

Comment: The model is MyClass, in it I have a dictionary columns with keys "name" and "type" (and more). I also use MVC3 and razor.

Comment: In case you are still facing issue, you can try alternative way of CheckboxList custom helper, which people have already implemented. Try links below

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/05/05/asp-net-mvc-implementing-checkboxlist.aspx

http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckBox%20list%20for%20selecting%20elements

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want something like this, for the default binder to understand the `name=""` format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="columns[0].Value" value="Key0 string value" />
<input type="checkbox" name="columns[1].Value" value="Key1 string value" />
```

Unfortunately the default helpers don't fully support this so you've to write the `name=""` explicitly. Something like:

```
@Html.CheckBox("columns[" + i + "].Value", new { value = columns[i].Key });
```

Read more about these kind of bindings on [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) blog post.